# How to use UDP with Asyncio for multiple file transfer from server to client - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

I want to transfer data (multiple images of size > 3 MB) from server to client. Since I want to test the packet loss with no re-transmission, I don't want to use stream (TCP).

I went through this [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#udp-echo-server). My approach is that, the server reads chunk of data using `f.read(1024)`and send to the client using `transport.sendto(data + seq_num)`. Reading and sending will continue in a loop until end of file.
 The client will  receive through `datagram_received(self, data, addr):`.Since I send sequence number (*seq_num*) along the data, I can control the lost segment and the order. My problem is on receiving and writing the data on the client side. How do I store data sent from server at different time on the client side with some condition with  `datagram_received (self, data, addr)` function?

Is there a feature that used to receive data from sock into the buf buffer?  e.g for stream (TCP) `data = await loop.sock_recv(tcp_sock, buf)`. I appreciate your help.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you hope to find a way to assemble your original data in order? If so - well, that’s what TCP IP is for. If you chose (for whatever good reason) to not use that, you will have to implement this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a feature that used to receive data from sock into the buf buffer? e.g for stream (TCP) `data = await loop.sock_recv(tcp_sock, buf)`.

As pointed out in the comment, datagrams can't provide a true streaming interface because UDP does not guarantee delivery order. If I understand the question correctly, you would like an *awaitable* interface to the event of the delivery of the next UDP packet, as the interface provided by default is purely callback-based.

Fortunately it is quite easy to convert a callback-based interface to an awaitable one - `asyncio` typically uses `Future` for that purpose, where the coroutine awaits the future, and the callback invokes `set_result()` to pass some data to the awaiting coroutine - see `on_con_lost` in the [sample UDP client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#udp-echo-client) from the docs.

A good stream-like API always supports some form of buffering, which can be provided by a limited-capacity queue:

```py
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self._received = asyncio.Queue(10)
        ...

    async def read_packet(self):
        return await self._received.get()

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        try:
            self._received.put_nowait((data, addr))
        except asyncio.QueueFull:
            log.error(f"dropped packet size {len(data)} from {addr}")
```

The limited-size queue allows processing of data to temporarily be slower than the rate at which data arrives, while preventing a memory leak in case the situation continues. After the queue is filled up, the packets are dropped. (With a TCP/IP-backed stream we would slow down reading to provide *backpressure* - well explained in [this article](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/), but with UDP there is no choice but to drop.)

Comment: Thanks for for the good explanation. yes, I was looking 'awaitable interface to the event of the delivery of the next UDP packet'. I now get a better understanding from your code snippet. Since observing packet drop is my main goal, I am sticking to UDP. 
Can I also set a timeout and stop listing the incoming data from the client?

Comment: @ewalel You can use `asyncio.wait_for` to implement timeout anywhere in asyncio, e.g. instead of awaiting `self.read_packet()`, you await `asyncio.wait_for(duration, self.read_packet())`. You can also flag another future when the packets drop, so you can even await _that_, and so on. Top stop listening for incoming data, I guess you'd just call `transport.close()`.